# Looking for a PDF reader for Windows with good usability in tablet mode

Tags: pdf, windows, usability

I have a Surface Pro 7, and when I bought it, I intended to use it for reading A4 sized PDF books. Now I find that I almost never do so, because of low app usability.

The features I am looking for in the software app are the ones typically found in good epub reading apps for Android.

1. (Knockout) Full screen view, with turn-one-page-at-a-time mode, with the option to switch to continuous mode.
2. (Knockout) Support for all typical kinds of PDF meant for book reading - typeset ones, scanned ones, scanned-with-ocr-overlayed ones. No need for support of archival features, signatures, 3D objects, XFA or other not-reading-related bells and whistles.
3. (Very important) Page turning by a tap in the lower right corner of the screen. Not a sweep, and not in any other location - for one-handed use, I have to be able to do a simple tap where my right thumb is.
4. (Very important) No other actions (such as selection of text or pictures) being mapped to a gesture very similar to the page-turning tap.
5. (Important) If I change to continuous-mode instead of single-page, the paging tap should be mapped to go down one screen, not to jump to the next document page. If I have zoomed in and scrolled horizontally in continuous mode, then the paging tap should remember the horizontally scrolled position, and not jump to the lefthand edge of the page.
6. (Important) Bookmarks. I don't have to write an annotation, but I want to place a marker here and there throughout the book. And in a non-reading mode, I want to be able to see a list of all bookmarks at once, so I can navigate between them.
7. (Important) Touch-based controls. For example, if the document has a rotated page inserted (usually some kind of table in a tiny font), I want to be able to rotate it to fill the screen and physically turn the tablet in my hand - without attaching a keyboard.
8. (Nice to have) On opening a file, it will already start in the correctly rotated full-screen reading mode, in the last place where it was closed.
9. (Very important) The app is not connected to any kind of web service which tracks what I read, or synchronizes my files to an app-provider-controlledcloud.
10. (Nice to have) Easily control the light intensity, such as the drag-finger-along-left-edge like on Moon+ for Android.

I don't need some other common reader features such as text reflow, control over the document appearance, dictionary, or sync between devices.

So far, I have tried Adobe Reader and Sumatra PDF, but both are very obviously not meant for tablet reading, and so they behave super clunky and I spend more time operating the app than reading.

I am OK with an app which doesn't bring this all out of the box, if there is a way to change the settings to behave as described, and to remember the changed settings permanently.